# How to submit a form on Ajax success:

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to validate the inputs with jQuery. If the inputs are validated and if ajax returns   `success` Then I need to allow the form to submit. I'm preventing the submit with `e.preventDefault`

My Script is :

```
$("#spsignin").submit(function(e){
    if (e.preventDefault) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    } else { 
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
    var uname = $("input#name").val();
    var pass = $("input#password").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login",
        data: 'uname=' + encodeURIComponent(uname) + '&' + 'pass=' 
                       + encodeURIComponent(pass),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data == true) {
                $("#spsignin").submit();
            } else { //display error message
                $("#error").show(1500).css({visibility: "visible"});
                $("#error").append("<b>Invalid Username/Email or Password</b>");
            }
        },
        //If there was no resonse from the server
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
            $("#error").html(jqXHR.responseText);
        },
    });
```

On `success` it performs submit action but it performing the action repeatedly. Means Firebug showing number of `post` requests in its console. And number of `post` requests in response too.

And form is:

```
<form action="Signin" method="get" id="spsignin">
    <input type="text" name="uname" class="text validate[required]" 
        id="name" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="pass" class="text validate[required]" 
        id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="" id="memberlogin"/>
</form>
```

Please anyone tell me how to submit the form on ajax `success` ... Thanks ...

Comment: why are you submitting the form that's already submitted thru ajax...

Comment: It is submitting repeatedly because *you* are asking it to. You are calling the `submit` function in the `submit` function

Comment: @Sudhir I'm just validating the inputs through ajax . And I need to create a session for the user and need to redirect him to other page

Comment: @Abhilash That's right. Then why it is not redirecting to other page. In my servlet I'm redirecting the user to other page...

Comment: Ajax is not going to let you redirect in your servlet. You'll have to set it in the `success` callback using `location.href`. <sheepish>Update: Didn't see the answer. This is pretty much what @Sudhir says, with code</sheepish>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inputs are validated, then you could log the user in, create session from the same code and redirect to appropriate page in your success callback, like

```
...
success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if(data==true) {
   //redirect to loggedin page
   location.href = "url_to_your_loggedin_page";               
  }
```