# Submit an AJAX FORM from within an AJAX Success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to perform another AJAX Form Post from within the first forms success function.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rZ2gx6G.jpg]

Example, this does 2 AJAX requests.
**Search Movie => Pick Movie Wanted => View Specific Movie Details**

I am able to load the results into a div `<div id="results"></div>` just fine but once I select a movie title it isnt performing another AJAX Request, the request goes to the main window.

**Here is the initial search page that handles the results.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#searchtitle").submit(function() {
           var id = $(this).children('input[name="thetitle"]').attr('value');
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "s.php",
               data: $('#searchtitle').serialize(), 
               cache: false,
               success: function(data){
            $('#status').html(data);
               }
           });
          return false;
      });
   });

</script>

<form id="searchtitle">
   <input type="text" name="thetitle" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button expand postfix" value="Search" />
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

**s.php which returns results within #results**

```
<?php
   if(empty($_POST['thetitle'])) {
   ?>
<div class="alert-box error">
   <div class="alert-error"></div>
   Error: Nothing Found
</div>
<?php
   }
   if(!empty($_POST['thetitle'])) {
      $myid = strtoupper($_POST['thetitle']);

      $searchReults = $tmdb_V3->searchMovie($myid,'en');
      ?>
<?php
   foreach($searchReults['results'] as $result) {
   ?>
<form class="sform">
   <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo $result['id']); ?>" />
   <h5><?php echo $result['title']; ?></h5>
   <span class="mreleased">Year: <?php echo $result['year']; ?></span>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Select">
</form>
<?php
   }
   }
   ?>
```

**This is the code that will post the results from s.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".sform").submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sx.php',
        data: $(this).closest("form").serialize();
        success: function (response) {
            $('#status').load(response);
            $('#status').find('script').each(function (i) {
                eval($(this).text());
            });

        }
    });

    return false;
}  
</script>
```

I have tried putting this within s.php, within the bottom of the initial search page, in the head of the initial page and no luck, it submits fine just not the sx.php where it should.

Comment: Move that form submit function from outside of that file, place it in the same file. Then, within the first ajax success function, call `$('.sform').submit();`

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065725/how-to-submit-a-form-on-ajax-success?rq=1

Comment: can you provide your form structure so that we can setup and check?

Comment: @maximkou No duplicate here. That isn't even what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy this does not work for me, your solution submits the form from within the results right away. I need the user to be able to choose what one he wants and then hit the submit button to retrieve the details.

Comment: Change your buttons from type 'submit' to type 'button' with an id that can be used to retrieve the required data and call your ajax from the onClick() method.  eval() is unwise code.  It is desperately difficult to be sure you are not vulnerable to DOM injection - please try hard not to use it.

Comment: @cept0 How do you figure? Why don't you explain your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In s.php the statement:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo $result['id']); ?>" />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" /> //remove extra bracket
```

In your javascript code in s.php there are some typos:

```
data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(); // here should be comma not semicolon
```

After `return false` you should close the script properly `}` should be `});`.

And since you are trying to submit the dynamic content `$(".sform").submit(function ()` will not work. You should use `on` for dynamic contents. So the correct script would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('submit', '.sform', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sx.php',
        data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#status').load(response);
            $('#status').find('script').each(function (i) {
                eval($(this).text());
            });

        }
    });

    return false;
 });  
</script>
```

I have checked and verified in my localhost (with a simple setup). It is making both ajax request. Hope this helps!

Comment: You just solved my 3 day headache! This works flawlessly! Thank you!